# Handling sequences of mouse clicks where each click is dependant on previous ones

Tags: java, mouseclick-event

I am creating a tile based turn based game where you have multiple units under your command and they are controlled using mouse clicks (sort of like chess but with a lot more mechanics). They're all drawn using Java Graphics (g.drawImage or g.draw(shape)). Each mouse click from the user should carry out a certain task dependant on previous mouse clicks.

For example: To attack an enemy unit, you must first click your own unit, and then click an enemy unit. Or if you click your own unit but he has already attacked then your subsequent click on the enemy unit should not cause an attack.

The game uses a tick/render system where all user input is processed in the tick method (called multiple times a second) and then drawn to the screen using the render method(also called multiple times a second)

The way I have tackled this problem is using a lot of different variables and way too many if statements. I wont paste the whole code because it's very long but the handling mouse click section of it has been attatched below.

Once the tick method reaches a certain end it will call "checkwhattoshow" method which is even longer than this but it will give instructions to the render method to draw onto the screen.

The code half-works in respect to what i want it to, but what im mainly asking is if there is a more efficient way than making too many if statements and variables, to handle sequences of mouse clicks, as this all seems unnecessary and inefficient.

```
//class variables
private boolean unitclickedon; //if a friendly unit is selected
private int xTile, yTile; 
private int onlyonce; //helps me perform a block of code only once
private int prevxTile, prevyTile;
private int speed; //distance the unit can move
private int maxRange; //how far the unit can attack

private Tile tile, newTile;
private Unit unit;

    @Override
    public void tick() {

    //every time the left mouse button is clicked
    if (handler.getMouseManager().buttonJustPressed(MouseEvent.BUTTON1)) {

        //keep track of the tile you're clicking on
        xTile = handler.getPosition().getCoordX();
        yTile = handler.getPosition().getCoordY();

        //if clicking outside of map do nothing
        if (xTile > handler.getMap().getWidth() - 2
                || xTile < 1
                || yTile < 1
                || yTile > handler.getMap().getHeight() - 2) {
            return;
        }

        //if you click on a unit
        if (handler.getMap().getTileAt(xTile, yTile).getUnit() != null) {

            //save the tile and unit info
            tile = handler.getMap().getTileAt(xTile, yTile);
            unit = tile.getUnit();
            speed = unit.getSpeed();
            maxRange = unit.getMaxRange();

            //if nothing is currently selected at all
            //select the unit and exit this method.
            if (onlyonce++ == 0) {
                unitclickedon = true;
                prevxTile = xTile;
                prevyTile = yTile;
                //check what should render to the screen
                checkWhatToShow();
                return;
            }

            //if you've clicked on the same tile twice unselect the unit and reset 
            if (prevxTile == xTile && prevyTile == yTile) {
                unitclickedon = false;
                onlyonce = 0;
            } else { // you're clicking on another unit
                Unit prevUnit = handler.getMap().getUnit(prevxTile, prevyTile);
                if (prevUnit.getOwner() == unit.getOwner()) { //selecting another one of your units
                    unitclickedon = true;
                    //check what should render to the screen
                    checkWhatToShow();
                } else { //clicking an enemy unit
                    if (validAttack(prevxTile, xTile, prevyTile, yTile, maxRange + speed)) { //attack
                        System.out.println("attacking unit!");
                        unitclickedon = false;
                        prevUnit.setHasAttacked(true);
                        return;
                    } else { //cant attack
                        unitclickedon = false;
                        checkWhatToShow();
                    }

                }
            }

        } else { //if you're not clicking on a unit

            if (unitclickedon) { //you're attempting to move a unit

                if (validMove(prevxTile, xTile, prevyTile, yTile, speed)) { //move the unit if its legal

                    tile = handler.getMap().getTileAt(prevxTile, prevyTile);
                    unit = tile.getUnit();
                    if (!unit.isActive() || unit.hasMoved()) {
                        unitclickedon = false;
                        return;
                    } else { //move the unit
                        newTile = handler.getMap().getTileAt(xTile, yTile);
                        tile.removeUnit();
                        newTile.addUnit(unit);
                        unit.setHasMoved(true);
                        unitclickedon = false;
                        onlyonce = 0;
                    }
                } else { //dont move the unit because you're clicking outside of its range
                    unitclickedon = false;
                    onlyonce = 0;
                }
            } else { //you're not doing anything unit related
                unitclickedon = false;
                onlyonce = 0;
            }
        }
        //record your last click
        prevxTile = xTile;
        prevyTile = yTile;
    }
}
```

short version:
trying to tackle the problem of making a large version of this more efficient:

```
if (first mouse click does x1)
   if (second mouse click does y)
      third mouse click does z
   if (second mouse click was y2)
      third mouse click z2
if (first mouse click does x2)
   bla bla bla
```

then getting the final result and rendering it onto the screen

thanks and sorry if it doesnt make sense :c

Comment: Looks like you need to change the state of your context based on various  actions, which sounds like a candidate for the [state design pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/State_pattern). **P.S.**
 [Nice article on state pattern in gaming](http://gameprogrammingpatterns.com/state.html)

Answer (score 0):

**you can something similar to :

```
List<Rule> rules = .... ; // your n rules initialized here somehow
for(Rule r : rules) {
  if(r.condition()) {
    r.action();
  }
}**
```